# PyQt5 MessageBox cannot be closed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a problem with creating GUI with PyQT, I have attached the code for your reference. The problem is whenever a message box is shown, I cannot click OK or 'x' to close it. Can anyone show me how to deal with it? Thank you very much. 
Does anyone have the answer, I am very in need of it.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'button.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.9.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMessageBox
import os

class Ui_SubWindow(object):

    def showMessageBox(self, title, message):
        msgBox=QMessageBox()
        msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
        msgBox.setWindowTitle(title)
        msgBox.setText(message)
        msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
        msgBox.exec_()

    def checking_name(self):
        firstname=self.lineEdit.text()
        lastname=self.lineEdit_2.text()
        b=os.listdir(r'C:\Users\dngochuynh\PycharmProjects\fr-project\standalone\image folder\downsized image')
        for e in b:
            if str(firstname).lower() in e:
                if str(lastname).lower() in e:
                    os.remove(r'C:\Users\dngochuynh\PycharmProjects\fr-project\standalone\image folder\downsized image\{}'.format(e))
                    self.showMessageBox('Warning','Image is deleted')
            else:
                self.showMessageBox('Warning','Cannot find the image, please check if your typing is correct')

    def setupUi(self, SubWindow):
        SubWindow.setObjectName("SubWindow")
        SubWindow.resize(350, 307)
        SubWindow.setStyleSheet("")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(SubWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.forgetButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.forgetButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 230, 111, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.forgetButton.setFont(font)
        self.forgetButton.setObjectName("forgetButton")
        ####################################################
        self.forgetButton.clicked.connect(self.checking_name)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 71, 31))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 71, 31))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 140, 321, 61))
        self.label_3.setText("")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 110, 331, 111))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 20, 221, 31))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 60, 221, 31))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        SubWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(SubWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        SubWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(SubWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(SubWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, SubWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        SubWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("SubWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.forgetButton.setText(_translate("SubWindow", "Delete My Image"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("SubWindow", "First Name"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("SubWindow", "Last Name"))
        self.textBrowser.setHtml(_translate("SubWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">If because of privacy reason, you want to delete your image from the dabase. Please forllow the instruction:</p>\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">1. Enter your first name</p>\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">2. Enter your last name</p>\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">3. Press Delete My Image</p>\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">After that your image will be deleted from the database and the program will not recognize you, next time it running. </p></body></html>"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    SubWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_SubWindow()
    ui.setupUi(SubWindow)
    SubWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[link to code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1InBZt21R7bi21FFnmJxxM8gynUgkO7zl/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi, but I make some changes to the code, and I can run it, I make modification to the method showmessagebox, and i created checking name method. It can be run, the problem is that the message box cannot be closed

Comment: @Rooney, I think the warning is only dangerous when I make any changes to the button.ui (source file) then all the modifcation I make to button.py will be deleted. However, it is not important here, because when I run the program, the modification code did work, it is only that the message box cannot be closed. Do you have any suggestion for me?

Comment: do you know why the messagebox cannot be closed?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is not that the message box won't close, but that it reopens immediately after it is closed.  The way you have written your for statement, a message box will appear for every file in the directory regardless of if the it contains the first and last names.

Comment: Thank you, I have just discovered that. I have make the modification to the code already.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing the method `checking_name '

```
...
def checking_name(self):
    firstname = str(self.lineEdit.text()).lower()
    lastname  = str(self.lineEdit_2.text()).lower()
    b=os.listdir(r'C:\Users\dngochuynh\PycharmProjects\fr-project\standalone\image folder\downsized image')
    #for e in b:
    if (firstname in b) and firstname:
        if (lastname in b) and lastname:
            os.remove(r'C:\Users\dngochuynh\PycharmProjects\fr-project\standalone\image folder\downsized image\{}'.format(lastname))
            self.showMessageBox('Warning','{} Image is deleted'.format(lastname))
            self.lineEdit.setText("")
            self.lineEdit_2.setText("")
        else:
            self.showMessageBox('Warning','firstname != lastname')
    else:
        self.showMessageBox('Warning',
            'Cannot find the `{}` image, please check if your typing is correct'\
            .format(firstname))

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your answer, it is how I fixed the code

```
    def checking_name(self):
    firstname=self.lineEdit.text()
    lastname=self.lineEdit_2.text()
    os.chdir(r'C:\Users\dngochuynh\PycharmProjects\fr-project\standalone\image folder\downsize image2')
    list_image=os.listdir(r'C:\Users\dngochuynh\PycharmProjects\fr-project\standalone\image folder\downsize image2')
    for e in list_image:
        if (str(firstname).lower() in str(e).lower()) and (str(lastname).lower() in str(e).lower()):
            os.remove(r'C:\Users\dngochuynh\PycharmProjects\fr-project\standalone\image folder\downsize image2\{}'.format(e))
            self.showMessageBox('Confirmation','Image is deleted')
            break
    else:
        self.showMessageBox('Warning','Cannot find the image, please check if your typing is correct')
```